# I wanted to copy a file where a script file exist in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wanted to copy a file where a script file exist in all subdirectories

I tried this command

```
find . -type f -regex '.*.sh' -exec echo cp myfile.txt {} \;
```

The output is

```
cp myfile.txt ./b/e/e.sh
cp myfile.txt ./a/a.sh
cp myfile.txt ./c/f/f.sh
cp myfile.txt ./c/c.sh
```

I want the output to be

```
cp myfile.txt ./b/e
cp myfile.txt ./a
cp myfile.txt ./c/f
cp myfile.txt ./c
```

how can I change the output from find command to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why does your desired output ignore `f.sh` and `c.sh`?

Comment: I don't want to ignore them, but I did not write those two lines with f.sh and c.sh, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but:

```
.... -exec bash -c 'cp myfile.txt $(dirname {})' \;
```

Here is another one:

```
 find . -regex '.*.sh' -exec dirname {} \; | xargs -n 1 cp myfile.txt
```